# React useEffect isn't getting data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a single collection in the firestore and i want those data to be rendered in my Reactjs app.
But, unfortunately  it isn't getting any data from firebase.

React code :

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);
return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <h1>Hello World lets build Instagram</h1>
      <div className="app__body">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <Post
            caption={posts.caption}
            imageUrl={posts.imageUrl}
            username={posts.username}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Firebase firestore collection screenshot:

[image]

I don't know why it isn't getting data.
I cross-checked the firebase config and code :

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
//config
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage };
```

Comment: Is it making it into the onSnapshot callback? If yes, what do you get if you log out `console.log(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))`? If no, you may be getting an error, such as a permissions error. You can pass a second function into onSnapshot to listen for the errors.

Comment: @NicholasTower I tired logging, I actually get a the data..........

0: {imageUrl: "http://blog.addthiscdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/addthis-react-flux-javascript-scaling.png", caption: "I love react", username: "sai"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Then is it fixed? Sounds like you're getting the data now.

Comment: Nope. but it isn't rendering into the React. Let me edit the question so that you can see more code.

Comment: You're passing props like `caption={posts.caption}`. posts is an array; arrays have no `.caption` property. You meant to do `caption={post.caption}`, singular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a typo:

```
        caption={posts.caption}
        imageUrl={posts.imageUrl}
        username={posts.username}
```

should be:

```
        caption={post.caption}
        imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
        username={post.username}
```

(ie. no "s").